# Different lengths for variable in Rstudio

Tags: r, statistics, manova

I'm trying to run a Manova in Rstudio but run into an error whenever i try to execute it. I have 2 dataframes containing 2678 and 2051 rows and an equal amount of columns. I rbind these dataframes into 1 and create a new variable y with the dependent variables (column 1:28) and a new variable x containing the independent variable (column 29). The independent variable is a factor with levels "True" & "False". The dataframes are imported from an csv excel file. Whenever i try to run y against x with manova i get the following errors:

`manova(y ~ x, data = bigfile)`

*invalid type (list) for variable 'y'*

I then do `manova(unlist(y) ~ x, data = df)`

Which gives me this error:

*variable lengths differ (found for 'x')*

I've looked at similar problems on this platform but none of these solutions seem to work for my problem. However, when I import my entire dataset into JASP it does run a Manova. So I guess the problem has to do  with the way the data is imported/mutated in my dataset(s)

```
d <- data.frame("Label" = c("True", "False"), "v1" = c(21,14), "v2" = c(0.132, 0.456), "v3" = c(0.734, 0.824))
d2 <- data.frame("Label" = c("False", "False"), "v1" = c(48,18), "v2" = c(0.284, 0.137), "v3" = c(0.296, 0.112))

bigdf = rbind(d, d2)

y = cbind(bigdf[2:4])
x = bigdf[1]

aov = manova(y ~ x, data = bigdf)
```

Comment: I'm confused - you're talking about RStudio but then you have python code. Are you using python within the RStudio IDE?

Comment: Oh sorry, haven't had my coffee yet, let me update that

Comment: Fixed now! Still same question

Comment: There were a few errors in your code, which I fixed. Let me know if that is meant what you're trying to do. The error here is that you're trying to use a list as a dependent variable. If you run `manova(cbind(v1, v2, v3) ~ Label, data = bigdf)` that works.

Comment: When I use this code the unlist error dissappears except the "variable lengths differ (found for 'Label')" error still pops up.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this error with the code and data provided above.

Comment: Then the problem is in my data, could it be that this error is due to unbalanced classes ? Or is it just a fault inside the data?

Comment: The implication of the error is that you have a different number of rows in x and y. If you run `dim(y)` and `dim(x)` what do you get?

Comment: The dimension of y = 4729    28
The dimension of x = 4729    1

However, for a Manova equal balanced classes (so in this case rows) isn't obligatory right?